# to_representation takes two different value types

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, model

I don't understand `to_reprsentation(self, value)` well, I have a case like this

- when I use `postman` status returns "`ORDERED`, ..." when I post and create an order and the `value` in `to_reprsentation` is of type `int`
- when I open `localhost:8000/orders/`, I get `Order` object can't be converted into `int`, `value` is of type `Order` this time.

I searched every single article I found, I didn't understand both methods `to_representation` & `to_internal_value`

#### models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} - {self.price}"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['price']

    @property
    def images(self):
        for image in Image.objects.filter(product=self):
            yield image.src.url
```

and

```
class STATUS:
    UNORDERED = 0
    ORDERED = 1
    BEING_PROCESSED = 2
    BEING_DELIVERED = 3
    DELIVERED = 4
    RECEIVED = 5
    REFUND_REQUESTED = 6
```

and

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ORDER_STATUS = (
        (STATUS.UNORDERED, 'Unordered'),
        (STATUS.ORDERED, 'Ordered'),
        (STATUS.BEING_PROCESSED, 'Being processed'),
        (STATUS.BEING_PROCESSED, 'Being Delivered'),
        (STATUS.DELIVERED, 'Delivered'),
        (STATUS.RECEIVED, 'Received'),
        (STATUS.REFUND_REQUESTED, 'Refund requested')
    )

    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)  #
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=ORDER_STATUS, default=STATUS.UNORDERED)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['pk']
```

#### serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'price', 'images']

    def get_images(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        for url in obj.images:
            yield request.build_absolute_uri(url)


class StatusField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        try:
            if int(value) > STATUS.ORDERED:
                raise APIException("Can't update an ordered order.")
        except ValueError:
            raise APIException('Unknown order status code')
        except TypeError:
            raise APIException('Order status must be an integer.')
        return value

    def to_representation(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Order):
            return value.status if value.status <= STATUS.ORDERED else APIException('Hi')
        # if int(value) == 0:
        #     return "Unordered"
        # elif int(value) == 1:
        #     return "Ordered"
        # elif int(value) == 2:
        #     return "Being processed"
        # elif int(value) == 3:
        #     return "Being Delivered"
        # elif int(value) == 4:
        #     return "Delivered"
        # elif int(value) == 5:
        #     return "Received"
        # elif int(value) == 6:
        #     return "Refund requested"
        # raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid order status code')


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True)
    status = StatusField(queryset=Order.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', 'status', 'products']
        depth = 2

    def create(self, validated_data):  # needs auth
        products_list = validated_data.pop('products')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for product_data in products_list:
            product = Product.objects.create(**product_data)
            order.products.add(product)
        order.save()
        return order

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        products_data = validated_data.pop('products')

        if instance.status >= STATUS.ORDERED:
            raise APIException("Can't update an ordered order")

        instance.status = validated_data.get('status', instance.status)
```

If I use if isInstance, it will work but I do want to know why sometimes it returns `Order` & other times it returns `int`

docs said `The value argument will typically be a model instance.` and this didn't happen in my case.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields described in the serializer documentation are for custom relational fields. That's why the documentation generally says that a model instance is being entered. `status` field is for `serializers.IntegerField`, not for a `serializers.RelationField`.

There is no need to inherit a separate StatusField for status validation. Instead, you can use the `validate_<fieldname>` function. Validation is done on save.

```py
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate_status(self, value):
        try:
            if int(value) > STATUS.ORDERED:
                raise APIException("Can't update an ordered order.")
        except ValueError:
            raise APIException('Unknown order status code')
        except TypeError:
            raise APIException('Order status must be an integer.')
        return value
```

docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation

Plus, from django 3.0, you can use `models.IntegerChoices`. You can consider using this if you're using django 3.0. docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types

Comment: Hello, thanks for suggesting another way to solve this? however, I'm a bit concerned about why this doesn't work instead of getting another way to work, Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed `status` is defined as an `IntegerField` in the model, but in a serializer it is strange to be defined as a `RelatedField`. Once you've set the model and serializer types, you can get them to work somehow, but putting validation logic in to_internal_value is misused. In any case, you will only need to_internal_value and not to_representation. This is because to_internal_value is used when saving from the external API to the database and to_representation is used when converting from the database to the external API.

Comment: I was busy yesterday & I had no time to test, I'm gonna test today & tell you the result.

Comment: Yes I think this helped very much, Thank you!